# Why is that every provider tile works for leaflet except Esri.WorldImagery?

Tags: r, leaflet

Does anyone know why `Esri.WorldImagery` is not working for leaflet in the following example? Please keep in mind this is original `leaflet` examples. If that works for you, please let me know!

```
> # Background 2: World Imagery 
library(leaflet) 
m <- leaflet() %>%    
  addTiles() %>%    
  setView( lng = 2.34, lat = 48.85, zoom = 3 ) %>%   
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery") 
m
```

If I change the `addProviderTiles` to anything else form this [list](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/), then it works!

Comment: works fine for me ?

Comment: Refreshed my R to the latest version and still doesn't work for me!

Comment: Same problem here!